# Optimize css : many tables that contain tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have to render up to 1500 row using jquery plugin Datatables and twitter bootstrap css. In each row, there is a table that can contain up to 50 row.

Using chrome developper tools profiler and testing, the rendering is a real problem. For example, i have for 250 items displayed 219861 selector match for .table th, .table td.

How can i optimize this ?

I retrieve twitter bootstrap from [bootstrapcdn](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)

Comment: Wow! That's a huge number! `219861` selectors!!! :P

Comment: Don't display all the rows at once. Use datatables' built-in pagination functions.

Comment: Maybe use Facebook style page loading where more content loads as the user scrolls down?

Comment: May I suggest pagination? :)

Comment: Pagination is available :) I wanted to provide this "Display all the stuff" functionality but i may be a little bit crazy. And other stuff like image are loaded by ajax calls when in the viewports, but still a good idea, @BillyMoat.

Comment: If you're going to display 1500 rows at once, you'd better have a good reason for it. And in that case, just make sure your users know that a certain amount of delay is unavoidable when sorting that much data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i will limit maximum number of rows displayed to 200. No "display all the stuff" allowed.

I will try to optimize css too. Seems that there is a lot of definition of bootstrap css i don't use.

Answer (score 0):

I am a framework developer and I can share some of things I have faced and remember at this moment

1. When writing table inside table layout, don't use

   ```
    'box-sizing:border-box'
   ```

   Instead use 'content-box', otherwise it will create gaps between rows, not columns if you have specified or not specified borders. No style will help you to remove that.. This is very important while implementing nested table layout
2. Even if you are using DIV with table layout, take care 'max-width' does not work properly in some mozilla versions, for that you may have to maintain a "wrapper" DIV that is occupying the 100% width and 100% height of cell.
3. Maintain block lever wrappers inside cells and apply skins to it if it is table, because hover and focus will not apply properly.. Example: half filled hover skin observed in some modern browsers as well.
4. And while embedding those many elements dynamically instead of creating elements on fly and appending, prepare HTML string and append it, it does perform very well.. I have observed this. But modifying html renderer might look dirty, but all we need is performance

These are some things I remember at this point of time. If I am wrong somewhere please correct me..

*Suggestion* If you are targeting mobile browsers as well, then go for table layout until unless you have good expertise in dealing with div layout. `Floats` does not work properly in some mobile devices. And tables scaled properly with media Queries in mobiles as well.

Comment: Are you familiar with http://datatables.net ? I'm not sure any of your suggestions apply to that plugin.

Comment: @Blazemonger Hmm, I would say not exactly. I have seen the title and just answered the Question. May be this answer is not appropriate. But according to the question title I feel it would match somewhere.. If not, please vote to delete the answer. I never mind :-)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar situation with waaaay too much table data and had to solve it with pagination.  The HTML has to pull all that info and build that massive table before it will even start to render it, thus the horrible slowness.